# Advantage .NET Data Provider - AdsConnection - DataSource

Tags: .net, wcf, advantage-database-server

Does the full dictionary path need to be specified for the DataSource? I have tried using the database AliasName and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Alias are only supported in Delphi and C++Builder.  For ADO.NET you should store your connection strings in either the web.config or app.config file.  See the MSDN for more details and examples, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work for me. I am creating an WCF LOB Adapter and the DataSource needs to go in the Uri. Config files are not supported.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the WCF LOB model hopefully someone else will be able to give you some ideas.

Comment: This url http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb798126(BTS.10).aspx will provide you information about the WCF Adapter SDK